# Closing Jquery UI popup

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I wrote a Javascript function that uses Jquery-ui.
I am able to close the JQuery popup with

```
$(this).dialog("close")
```

But if I include it in an If condition, like it is in the code here, it just does not work.
Am i missing something on how the this keyword works in JS?

Marco

```
if (vars["server_url"] !== undefined)
        var serverUrl = vars["server_url"];
        var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
        var CRMObject = new Object();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
        // Specify the ODATA entity collection 
        var ODATA_EntityCollection = "/custom_serviceobjectSet";



        var alreadyExisting = new Object;
        alreadyExisting.value = "";
        retrieveExistingPlacement(serverUrl, custom_name, placering.val(), alreadyExisting);
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert(alreadyExisting.value);
            if (alreadyExisting.value === true) {

                placering.addClass("ui-state-error");
                updateTips("Ett ServiceObject med sån placeringen redan finns.");
            }
            else if (alreadyExisting.value === false)
            {
            //alert(ordning.val());
            $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
                "<td>" + CRMObject.custom_order + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + CRMObject.custom_Placement + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + CRMObject.custom_Quantity + "</td>" +
                "</tr>");
            var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(CRMObject);
            //Asynchronous AJAX function to Create a CRM record using OData 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                url: serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + ODATA_EntityCollection,
                data: jsonEntity,
                beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                    //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON. 
                    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {

                    var NewCRMRecordCreated = data["d"];
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + ODATA_EntityCollection);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            });
                alert("OUT");

            }
        }, 1000);
        if (alreadyExisting.value === false) 
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
}
```

Comment: Most of this code has nothing to do with your question. Select the dialog by `id` as `this` likely doesn't refer to it in this case.

Comment: I suggest stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: OFFTOP: most of your logic goes inside `if(bValid) {...}`. why not to return from function if `bValid` is false and save some indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    if (alreadyExisting.value === false) 
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
```

*this* no longer refers the dialog.  Access it through the id of the dialog box instead of using *this*

```
    if (alreadyExisting.value === false) 
        $("#dialogId").dialog("close");
    }
```

Comment: Doing it and changing the type of the XmlHttpRequest that checks if the record was already existing to sync made it work. It turned out that despite setting a timeout, the value was not updated on time for the checl

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking about this:

```
if (alreadyExisting.value === false) 
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

If that is the case, this conditional might never execute.  That is because a few lines earlier you do this:

```
alreadyExisting.value = "";
```

Of course you then call this:

```
retrieveExistingPlacement(serverUrl, custom_name, placering.val(), alreadyExisting);
```

Which, if it does not set `alreadyExisting.value` to `false` will mean the dialog close logic will never be triggered.  Whatever happens in `setTimeout()` function happens asynchronously, so it will not impact the value evaluated for `alreadyExisting.value`

Comment: retrieveExistingPlacement was updating the value, that is why I am using an Object instead of a variable.